# Column Filter Watermark is Not Showing in PrimeFaces in 6.0.19 Onwards

Tags: primefaces

Since PrimeFaces 6.0.19 onwards including 6.0.20 and 6.1.x(6.1.1 and 6.1.2) our code for column filter watermark is not working as below:

```html
<h:form id="myForm">
  <p:dataTable id="myTable">
    <p:column id="column2" filterBy="column2">
      <f:facet name="header">
      <p:watermark for="@(#myForm\\:myTable\\:column2\\:filter)"
      value="Watermark 2" />
      <h:outputText value="Column2" />
      </f:facet>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Before the version 6.0.19, our code is working well. I hope you can give us some tips on this on how to handle or display column filter watermark.
JSF:2.2
Payara Server(Glassfish Fork): 4.1.1.171 and 4.1.2.172
Primefaces: 6.0.19 including 6.0.20 and 6.1.x(6.1.1 and 6.1.2)

Comment: is your selector still 'good'?

Comment: for="@(#frmTenantList\\:singleDT\\:customerName\\:filter)" Nothing has changed... I am just seeking for the correct format and follow that. But before all the watermarks show up.

Comment: I tried other solutions based on other posts regarding  watermark issue in the filter but failed such as using the forElement given that this attribute is removed on the newer version of PrimeFaces. Then, I tried to use the FireDebug and then use Inspect. Then, I copied the ID using the CSS Selector. I noticed, that it should be #frmTenantList\:singleDT\:customerName\:filter with a single "\". Hence, it should be for="@(#frmTenantList\\:singleDT\\:customerName\\:filter)". I tested it and it worked! Therefore, the newer version starting 6.0.19 of PrimeFaces only accept single backslash "\".