# Unable to display watermark text for p:column with filter

Tags: primefaces

I'm on **Primefaces 6.2** and I have a p:dataTable with the below structure:

```
<h:form id="infocenterform">
...
...
    <p:dataTable id="infocentertable" ...>
    ...
    ...
    <p:column id="infocenterthemacolumn" style="width: 60%;" filterBy="#{eintrag.thema}" headerText="Thema" filteredValue="#{marketingPagesController.filteredEintragList}" sortBy="#{eintrag.thema}" filterMatchMode="contains">

            <h:outputLink value="#{eintrag.file}" target="_blank" >
                <h:outputText value="#{eintrag.thema}"/>
            </h:outputLink>                                  

            <p:watermark for="@(#infocenterform\\:infocentertable\\:infocenterthemacolumn\\:filter)" value="Search with a keyword" /> 

    </p:column>
```

**The watermark text isn't getting displayed** (the page rendering, filtering, sorting etc. all work fine). I referred to the watermark syntax as suggested by folks for **PF 6.1** on this page:
[How to show water mark in filter in primefaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522576/how-to-show-water-mark-in-filter-in-primefaces][1])

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just try `<p:watermark for="infocentertable:infocenterthemacolumn:filter)" value="Search with a keyword" /> `

Comment: Another thing to try is Press F12 in Chrome to bring up the JS Console and enter this script `$('#infocenterform\\: infocentertable\\: infocenterthemacolumn\\:filter').attr('placeholder','Search with a keyword');`  When you run that script in the console you should see your watermark appear in the filter.

Comment: @Melloware Thanks a lot for the suggestions. Sadly, neither of these two worked in my case. I don't get the watermark text. I think there may be something else wrong with my code, possibly? My xhtml is using composition..does that matter for the watermark?

Comment: Btw, I tried this other approach using the styleClass attribute and it brings up the watermark text:
`<p:column id="infocenterthemacolumn" styleClass="watermark1" style="width: 60%;" filterBy="#{eintrag.thema}" headerText="Thema" sortBy="#{eintrag.thema}" filterMatchMode="contains">

 <p:watermark for="@(.watermark1)" value="Search keyword...." />
 <h:outputText value="#{eintrag.thema}"/>
</p:column>`
...but on the other hand, having the watermark this way is badly affecting the speed of filtering the column..I don't know why.

Comment: (the styleClass way is discussed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018868/how-to-add-placeholder-text-in-the-filter-box-in-datatable-column-headers )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates: This syntax did work ultimately for me...but I had to **change the double slashes to single slashes** as below :)

```
<p:watermark for="@(#infocenterform\:infocentertable\:infocenterthemacolumn\:filter)" value="Search with a keyword" />
```

(followed from this post: [Column Filter Watermark is Not Showing in PrimeFaces in 6.0.19 Onwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44427332/column-filter-watermark-is-not-showing-in-primefaces-in-6-0-19-onwards))